# Connecting local spark to Hive remote

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, kerberos, cloudera

after trying a bunch of things I would like to know if there's a way to connect local spark to Hive without getting this error -

This happens right after I successfully login through kerberos.

I have copied my hive-site.xml from server to local, as spark on server is working perfectly fine.

Am I missing any files?

Hi, after trying a bunch of things I would like to know if there's a way to connect local spark to Hive without getting this error -

```
23/07/12 13:26:58 ERROR metastore: Couldn't create client transport
java.io.IOException: Could not instantiate SASL transport
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Client.createClientTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1740)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.databaseExists(Hive.java:1552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_12.databaseExists(HiveShim.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:398)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:223)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupGlobalTempView(SessionCatalog.scala:949)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.lookupTempView(Analyzer.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupRelation(Analyzer.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$13.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.OrderPreservingUnaryNode.mapChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Distinct.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:987)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:617)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context [Caused by GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: krb5.conf loading failed)]
    at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:160)
    at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.FactoryImpl.createSaslClient(FactoryImpl.java:63)
    at java.security.sasl/javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:433)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.<init>(TSaslClientTransport.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Client$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Client$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:209)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Client.createClientTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:208)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: krb5.conf loading failed)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:99)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:197)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:478)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:132)
    at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:108)
    ... 150 more
23/07/12 13:26:58 ERROR metastore: Unable to connect to metastore with URI thrift://... in attempt 0
MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: Could not instantiate SASL transport)
```